# What does the last return statement in the code below mean exactly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm very new to python. I found some help online with the body of this function (i removed the examples to shorten it) however i'm confused about what the 'return true' statement means in relation to the body of the code as a whole. I understand the first if statement but not the 'return True' statement since there is no elif or else with it. I also noticed that the return True statement is not indented under the if statement. Does this explain anything? Thanks!

```
def is_valid_sequence(dna):
   """ (str) -> bool

   Return True if and only if the DNA sequence is valid
   (that is, it contains no characters other than 'A', 'T', 'C' and 'G').
   """
   valid_dna = 'ACGT'
   for nucleotide in dna:
       if nucleotide not in valid_dna:
           return False
   return True
```

Comment: Why would there need to be an `else`? When the `for` loop ends without the `if` ever matching, the last line is reached. If the `if` test *does* match for one of the `nucleotide` values, then the `return False` is reached and the function ends.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. One way to see how this code works is to add print statements to help you follow the flow. You can also download [PyCharm Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) and use its debugger.

Comment: Or try http://pythontutor.com/

Comment: Imagine it this way, "the function should always `return True`, unless intercepted by another `return` statement".  In this case, if the condition for `return False` passes, the function will exit at that point.  Now, even if you didn't have any `return True` statement, the function would silently `return None` by default.  Test this it for yourself.  Try running this function without the last line and seeing it's `type()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only when the `for` loop ends without the `if` ever matching, is the last line is reached. At that point you know that all `nucleotide` test are valid DNA characters.

If the `if` test *does* match for one of the `nucleotide` values, then the `return False` is reached and the function ends.

So the code tests *every `nucleotide` value in `dna`* until either an invalid `nucleotide` value is found (so `if nucleotide not in valid_dna` is true and `return False` is executed), or all the values have been tested and the `for` loop ends, and `return True` is executed.

If, on the other hand, you used an `else` block for the `if` test, then only the *first* `nucleotide` value was tested and you returned `True` too early, without testing the rest of the `dna` sequence.

You could step through the code using two examples, `AGFT` and `AGCT`. The first is not valid DNA, the second one *is*.

For `AGFT`, the code does this:

- `nucleotide = 'A',`if nucleotide not in valid_dna`is *False* so the`if` test doesn't match and the loop continues from the top again.
- `nucleotide = 'G',`if nucleotide not in valid_dna`is *False* so the`if` test doesn't match and the loop continues from the top again.
- `nucleotide = 'F',`if nucleotide not in valid_dna`is *True* so the`if`test **does** match and`return False`is reached. The function ends, returning`False`.

For `AGCT`, the sequence of events is:

- `nucleotide = 'A',`if nucleotide not in valid_dna`is *False* so the`if` test doesn't match and the loop continues from the top again.
- `nucleotide = 'G',`if nucleotide not in valid_dna`is *False* so the`if` test doesn't match and the loop continues from the top again.
- `nucleotide = 'C',`if nucleotide not in valid_dna`is *False* so the`if` test doesn't match and the loop continues from the top again.
- `nucleotide = 'T',`if nucleotide not in valid_dna`is *False* so the`if` test doesn't match and the loop continues from the top again.
- There are no more nucleotides to test. The loop ends.
- The line `return True` is reached. The function ends, returning `True`.

Answer (score 0):

It means if every item in the loop doesn't return a false, you will return a true in the end.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the if statements in the for loop is true, the function will *return False* which means leave the function and give back *False*.

If none of the if statements in the for loop is true, the for loop will go through all *nucleotides* in *dna* and then go to the next statement where it returns *True*.

Answer (score 0):

If there is one invalid character in string `dna`, then this function will return `False`.
If you have looped over the whole `dna`, and don't find anything bad, then this function returns `True` in the end.